# Regular expression in Matlab to leave only specified items of an array

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a list of channels:

```
channels = {'1LT1', '1LT2', '1LT3', '1LT4', '1LT5', '2LA1', '2LA2', '2LA3', '3LH1', '3LH5', '4LT1', '4LT2', '4LT3', '5LH1', '5LH2', '4LT10'}
```

I need to write an alogrithm to leave only distal channels. It means for each type of channel ('1LT', '2LA', '3LH', '4LT' and etc.) I need only channel with the highest last number. The best way is to return indexes of these channels. For example, for abovementioned list the results should be:

```
[5, 8, 10, 15, 16]
```

I think I can do it with regexp by splitting like that:

```
row_i = 1;
for ch_i=[1:length(channels)]
    try
        [n(row_i,:), ch_type(row_i,:)] = strsplit(channels{ch_i},'\d+[A-Z]', 'DelimiterType','RegularExpression');
        row_i = row_i + 1;
    catch
        continue
    end
end
```

But then I am really stuck. Can somebody give me some tips to create good algorithm?

I am thankful for any idea!

Comment: *to create good algorithm?* in which sense?

Comment: Works without mistake and ignores useless channels (for example, 'Event', 'C125'). The pattern is always numbers(1-2)-letters(many)-numbers(1-2) (I guess in regexp: \d+[A-Z]*\d+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to break each string into a channel and number, create numeric labels for the channels using [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html), convert the number string into an actual number with [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), then [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) to find the max for each group. Here's the code, although I can't test it right now so it may need some tweaks:

```
tokens = regexp(channels, '(\d+[A-Z]+)(\d+)', 'tokens');
tokens = vertcat(tokens{:});
[grps, channelID] = findgroups(tokens(:, 1));
nums = str2double(tokens(:, 2));
channelMax = splitapply(@max, nums, grps);
```

Using the `channelID` and `channelMax` values, you can then reconstruct the distal channel names and find their indices in the channel list using [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
distal = strsplit(sprintf('%s%d\n', channelID, channelMax));
index = find(ismember(channels, distal));
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! In my case number of letter not always two - I guess [A-Z]* is better. But I don't understand why this code is sensitive for outliers (for example, C125 - which is not satistifed regexp pattern).

Comment: @EgorLevchenko: Are you saying that C125 matches with my code, or when you use [A-Z]*? It shouldn't match with mine. You may need to use [A-Z]+.

Comment: Yes, I mean if I use [A-Z]*, but you're right - [A-Z]+ is better.

Comment: I just changed channelMax to string (string(channelMax)), made `strcat(channelID, channelMax)` instead of `strsplit(...)` and add one more repeat of `vertcat(...)`. It works good, thank you!